# Vim alternatives file

Tags: vim

```
:[range]s/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
            For each line in [range] replace a match of {pattern}
            with {string}.

The "or" operator in a pattern is "\|".  Example:
    /foo\|bar
This matches "foo" or "bar".  More alternatives can be concatenated:
    /one\|two\|three
Matches "one", "two" and "three".
```

Can we use a pattern/alternatives file with 3 lines?
one
two
three

Comment: Use the pattern: `\vone\ntwo\nthree` if what you want is to match those three words in consecutive lines

Comment: OK. I have 100 or 1000 possible words to replace. It is unfeasible to use:
:s /one\|two\|three\|four\|five\|six\|seven ...\|one_hundred/replacement/g
I want to put all 100 or 1000 replacement candidates into a file. something like grep -f. Is that possible?
If you want to insert an external file you use :r extfile.txt is that something similar in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The following command works on my system:

`let @a = system('cat repl.vim | tr "\n" "|"') | exe '%s/\v'.@a.'<bs>/x/g'`

Here, I have a list of words in the file `repl.vim`. The first part of the command uses `let` to save the list of words in registry `a` replacing every newline `\n` with an or operator `|`. In the second part `exe %s` performs the substitution.

In practice, if repl.vim contains:

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
```

Running the command will result in:

```
%s/\vpattern1|pattern2|pattern3/x/g
```